# Triple integral of a regular otctahedron

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to express the volume of a regular octahedron as a single triple integral in rectangular coordinates, with vertices $(\pm 1, 0, 0),(0,\pm 1, 0 ), (0,0, \pm 1)$ centred at the origin. From inspecting the shape, I believe this can't be done without just dealing with one quarter of it, is this right? Or can it be expressed in total without needing to be $4*\int\int\int_{\frac{R}{4}} \mathrm{dx \; dy \; dz}$$

Question: All I am asking is, whether or not it is possible to make the triple integral without splitting it?
 Would it be possible to do in cylindrical or spherical coordinates?

Comment: If you're willing to use absolute values in your limits of integration, you can write a single integral: $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, $|x| - 1 \leq y \leq 1 - |x|$, etc.

Comment: In regards to being possible, I have to say yes.

Comment: I don't think using cylindrical coordinates or spherical coordinates are necessary for this problem.

Comment: @usukidoll could you please do this question for me, I need to see one example so I can so the next few textbook questions